# Why the less than $<$ relation is considered a total relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm reading these Spanish classroom notes about [relations and functions](https://sistemasacademico.uniandes.edu.co/%7Eisis1104/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=enlaces:v5:v5_6_relaciones_y_funciones.pdf) (section 6.1.1), I have found that the less than $<$ operator is considered a **total relation**. Here is its definition:

$(\forall a:A|:(\forall b:B|:aRb))$

and this is the example:

$.<.: \mathbb{N}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Why this relation is considered total?

Comment: A total relation is one in which every pair of distinct elements are comparable.  I.e. if $x\neq y$ then $x\mathcal{R}y$ or $y\mathcal{R} x$.

Comment: I've no idea what on earth the strange notation means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, a relation $R \subseteq X \times Y$ is said to be **[left-total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations)** if for each $x \in X$, there is some $y \in Y$ such that $(x, y) \in R$ so that $xRy$. This is basically the opposite definition for what it means to be surjective (right-total), and should not be confused with the definition of a *total* relation (this applies for the special case where $X = Y$, and we say that any two elements are *comparable* because for any $x, y \in X$, we have that $(x, y) \in R$ or $(y, x) \in R$).

To see that $<\, \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ is **left-total**, observe that for any $x \in \mathbb N$, we can take $y = x + 1$ and observe that $x < x + 1 = y$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

A (non-strict) total relation on $S$ is a relation $\le$ such that $x \le y$ or $y \le x$ for any $x,y \in S$.

A strict total relation on $S$ is a relation $<$ such that $x < y$ or $y < x$ or $x = y$ for any $x,y \in S$.

Comment: Here you have a strict total relation on $\mathbb{N}$.